# Permutation and Combination of SubCategories

Tags: algorithm, permutation

I have 5 categories and each has sub-categories.

```
Category   Sub-Categories
---------  ----------------
A             6
B             7
C             15
D             22
E             10
```

And I want to calculate Total Number Of possible permutations and combinations out of these.

I am getting number permutations = 4069302 and combinations = 7019801 , Which I think is a wrong answer.

My Approch is like this (A1*B1+A1*B2+..)+(B1*C1+B1*C2+..).

I know there are many questions-answers available on permutations and combinations.
But I am very much confused, please help me solving this particular problem and getting correct number of permutations and combinations.

Comment: What are you choosing out of those categories and subcategories?  One subcategory from each category?

Comment: Yes.All possible combinations from all categories and subcategories.

Comment: What is an example of one result?  (A1,B1,C1,D1,E1)  or (A1,A2,A3,...E9,E10)?

Comment: How do you define a permutation and combination for this problem?

Comment: @Vaughn - I need to get like (A1,B1,C1,D1,E1)... unique combinations and total count of such combinations.

Comment: Can the categories come out in different orders?  For example is (B1,D1,A1,C1,E1) also a valid result?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [math.se].

Comment: @ Vaughn - Any order is fine, but combination should not be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

I will first try to describe how I understood the problem.

You have `N` categories. Each category has `Si` subcategories.

You want to get the *number of ways to pick exactly one subcategory from each category*. So `A1, B2, C3, D1, E2`, or `A2, B1, C1, D1, E5`...

You have `S1` possible choices for category 1, `S2` for category 2... So the answer is the product of `Si` - for the example you posted, **6 * 7 * 15 * 22 * 10 = 138600**.

So far, this is order-invariant, it only counts solutions that different sets of subcategories. If the order matters (A1, B1, ... != B1, A1, ...):

There are `N!` permutations for each of our solutions. So the answer is the product of `Si` (as above) `* N!`. In your example, this is **138600 * 6! = 99792000**.

I believe one of these covers what you are thinking of when you say "combinations". When it comes to permutations, you need to describe what you mean when you say permutations. Permutations *of what*?